# How to change the value of navigator.language in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, language, locale

My browser is in English and I have removed all other languages, but when I go to the console and look up `navigator.language` it shows a value of `"bg-BG"` and `navigator.languages` is `["bg-BG", "en"]`.

I tried normal and hard reloads of the page, restarting Chrome, clearing the browsing data, even restoring the settings to their original defaults. Then I decided that if not removing it I can maybe move it lower if I add Bulgarian as a language and move that lower and now `navigator.languages` is equal to `["bg-BG", "en", "bg"]`.

If I add a new person to Chrome they don't have `"bg-BG"` in their `navigator.languages` and their default is English.

edit: I found a way that temporarily fixes it. If I select a language and pick `Move to the top` it will go above `bg-BG`, but newly added languages will still go under it. So it's still in the list in the languages settings, just hidden and unselectable.

Comment: Change it using standard settings UI ( goto `chrome://settings/?search=lang`).

Comment: That's what I've been doing. I'm not aware of other ways to change the language.

Comment: Do you have the issue in Chrome 73 ?              Read https://crbug.com/784740 ?